# Drupal 7 Orphaned fields, how should they be deleted?

Tags: 7, entities, ubercart, database

Currently I uninstalled ubercart and there are still fields that exists in my database. I have the following fields that I want to delete:

- uc_catalog_image
- uc_product_image

http://prntscr.com/1hj1rt

How should one go about deleting these tables from the database? What would it affect if I just dropped those tables complete? And where else would I have to update if I did that manually?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using drush for this type of thing and let the field crud api do the heavy lifting.
`drush eval field_delete_field("YOUR_FIELD_GOES_HERE")`